# Firebase Crash Reporting : FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-crash-reporting

This an exception I encountered when trying to use FirebaseAuth and Firebase Crash Reporting. I am trying to sign in anonymously in my application `onCreate`

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseAuth.signInAnonymously().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.wtf("TAG", "Signed signInAnonymously successful ");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I also want to use crash reporting so my gradle dependencies looks like this.

```
dependencies {
    // other dependencies
    // ...

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.2.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

After a certain amount of time I will get a crash dialog and this exception. Its another process that crashes so the app itself will still run.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist. 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4612)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:169)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1337)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist. 
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.redstar.collectors.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:22)
    at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.onCreate(BootstrapApplication.java:369)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1013)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4609)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:169) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1337) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

If I remove the firebase-crash dependency there will be no crash.

Comment: This is a race condition between your initialization code and some auto-initialization code in Firebase. You'll want to move the initialization into your main activity (where it runs later) or preferably into a content provider (where it runs earlier).

Answer (score 2):

`FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist` is caused when you run Firebase code on the separate process that is created by Firebase Crash Reporting as your custom `Application` class is created for each process in your app.

You should move code from your `Application` class to somewhere else. This could be in your main activity (which would always be in your main process) or could be in the `onCreate()` of a separate `ContentProvider` you register in your Manifest (a `ContentProvider`'s `onCreate()` is run once in the lifecycle of your app's process just like `Application.onCreate()`, but only runs in a single process).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. An issue I have with putting the code in my main activity is my main activity is not guaranteed to be to be launched every time. For example I won't open my main activity if I launch from a share intent. So I could have duplicate code or a base activity, both of which Id rather not. A content provider seems kind of strange as Im not actually going to provide any content. Maybe injecting is the way to go?

Comment: Yep, totally agree with the odd feel of the ContentProvider approach. You can most definitely have the code as a static method in a class and call it from each component where you need to make sure it is ready - a static boolean for if you've already done the setup would ensure it is only done once per process initialization.

Comment: Ok maybe thats the best way to go about it. Thanks. As a side, is it really necessary to run Firebase crash reporting in a seperate process?

Comment: @Modge - that's a requirement with the current version, although I seem to remember seeing on the [Firebase forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-talk) that they're hoping to remove that requirement.